# Limit lengths of items in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a summary of the descriptions in my array because it is acting as a link to the full post.

So for example. "I went to the park today" would become "I went to th..."

I have tried the following without any success.

The array I need to alter is $description[]

```
foreach ($description as $descriptions) {

  $descriptions = substr($descriptions, 0, 12); 
  $description = ($description + '...');
}
```

Comment: can u do var_dump($description) and post to the question ? and how u want them to display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and use new variable `$desc`

```
$desc = array();
foreach ($description as $descriptions) {
$desc[] = substr($descriptions, 0, 12).'...'; 
}
```

Comment: You have to use . for concatenation , not +

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/array_walk) to directly modify the elements in the array..

```
array_walk($description,function (&$v){ $v=substr($v, 0, 12)."...";});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do:

```
$descriptions = array('something' => 'I went to the park today');
foreach ($descriptions as $index => $value) {
    $value = substr($value, 0, 12); 
    $descriptions[$index] = ($value . '...'); 
}
```

now, `$descriptions` wil be `Array ( [something] => I went to th... )`

Answer (score 0):

try following.

```
foreach ($description as $descriptions) {    
    $descriptions = substr($descriptions, 0, 12);     
    $descriptions = ($descriptions . '...');
 }
```